# Telegram Bot: job_queue.run_repeating cannot properly callback

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have been wrestling with this for a while. I can't seem to get the `job_queue.run_repeating` to call back a function properly.

My goal is for the user to issue command in the form of `/alert` to begin running the `send_alert` function on a fixed interval. I am not sure where I am going wrong despite having looked at at several examples. I can get regular commands to execute just fine, but not JobQueue callbacks.

Currently my code below throws an error on the `start_alerts` callback, saying `NameError: name 'job_queue' is not defined`. When I add job_queue accordingly to the function call, such as `start_alerts(update, context, job_queue)` it no longer updates the "alerts started!" message to my Telegram chat, but it also doesn't throw an error.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, JobQueue

def start_alerts(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="alerts started!")
    job_queue.run_repeating(send_alert, interval=5.0, first=1.0)

def send_alert(update, context):
    message="this is an alert to send"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)

updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
job_queue = updater.job_queue
job_queue.set_dispatcher(dispatcher)

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('alert', start_alerts))

updater.start_polling()
job_queue.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `start_alerts` function, the variable `job_queue` is not defined. Use `context.job_queue` instead as explained in the [`JobQueue` tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue), the [`timerbot.py` example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#timerbotpy) and the documentation of [`CallbackContext`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html#telegram.ext.CallbackContext.job_queue).